# Typesafe event handlers with Preact + Typescript

Tags: typescript, preact

I am writing a simple component with Preact that uses an `onChange` handler for an `<input/>` element:

```
function Example(props: {}) {
  return <input onChange={(e) => {
    const { value } = e.currentTarget;
    console.log(value);
  }} />
}
```

The code above creates the following error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)
```

The quickest fix would be to do a typecast:

```
    const el = (e.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

but I **do not want to add type casts to the application** for such a common operation.

What is the correct way to write a form event handler **without using typecasts or the `any` type?**

Environment Info:

- `"strict": true` in tsconfig.json
- `preact@8.5.2`
- No external typings installed. Using package defaults.

Comment: can you specify which config of typescript you are using, also which @types?

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev I have updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767519/correct-types-for-preact-event-objects-when-not-using-compat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work on Preact.

This is a bug in our current typings for Preact. Those are distributed with the `preact` npm package itself. Here is an issue in our tracker that is related to that: https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/1930

Comment: It looks like although that bug report is still open, the types have been improved at least in part, enough at least that the example in the question no longer causes an error -- the type of `currentTarget` in their example is now `HTMLInputElement` as one would expect.