# Correct types for Preact event objects when not using compat?

Tags: typescript, preact

I'm struggling with the correct types to use for event objects with Preact when not using `preact/compat`. It's fine with inline event handlers because they get their types from the props you're using (`onInput`, etc.), but if you're writing the handler separately, it's trickier. I can use the type ultimately referenced by the prop, but I suspect I'm missing something. Let's use an `input` (or `change`) handler as an example:

```typescript
const onInput = (event: WhatTypeShouldIUseHere) => {
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...use `event.currentTarget.value` here...
};
```

So far, the best I've found is to use `JSX.TargetedEvent` (lifted from the `onInput` prop's type), like this ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgKQMoA04F84DMoQhwBEYUApgIYDGMxA3ALABQL1EAdgM7ycCSHMAFd4AXjgAKcgC4UGAHQAVSlADm5GOQAmAUQBu5DjAA8ACUUBZADIDhMHQBtyIQzAB8ASjii3iFnAC4dm4IJ3kHCFUpeWohKAojZTUNeT1KByFyDyZmLBy2Th44cicXI284Y2BBETh+GphRBHq7HAB6N3ogA)):

```typescript
import { JSX } from "preact";
// ...
const onInput = (event: JSX.TargetedEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // ...use `event.currentTarget.value` here...
};
```

Is this the correct, idiomatic way, or am I missing a trick?

I should note explicitly that I don't want to use type assertions in the handler code (see my comments on what the documentation says below for more on that).

In a React codebase, it would be `ChangeEvent`, like this:

```typescript
import { ChangeEvent } from "react";
// ...
const onChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // ...use `event.currentTarget.value` here...
};
```

*(`onChange` instead of `onInput` because React uses that for `input` events.)*

[The documentation](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/typescript/#typing-events) (quoted below¹) says to use the DOM event interfaces and/or to use a `this` parameter with a type annotation. The former works for some things (like keyboard events), but not if you want to handle an `input` or `change` event and access `event.currentTarget.value` without a type assertion, since on the DOM event interfaces, both `currentTarget` and `target` are simply typed as `EventTarget`. The latter (a typed `this` parameter, so you could do `this.value`) has two issues: <s>A) [It doesn't seem to work anymore](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7Aph+BfOAMyjTgCIwosBDAYxjIG4AoZrAD0ljloBtqAzgLgAhAK4wYmOBxg4AJsNTpsuRMzia4Aem1wAgvPnAMAczgwAFlguXgw6lFNiQOeFQEwowesIBGJsZmGlqW1BjyvFjIvD4A1gAUVvYAXHAAEgAqALIAMuKSmACiUa64ADQyAG5uadkQYgJYRTW4AJTqWl3VbgB0lFitMAAiWITUYrwwCW0s3VrAhHAJg30wjqZY8Cae4bRYEEtZeSVYZTAdCCHzXbSYAhBRvbwQpitDvetOW88QtNS8ABy1Fcsx0ejIfgkUgwZGu3Tw8MR8KoESwUBmnRuVBgYigGDgAB4oYUCZgYvEALwIZICXphCJRCm0OJ4AB8NLsdMoEDAdNodl48lReEJ2hJMLZcy0iMRQA) (details below²) *(I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/3938), in general their docs are **excellent**)*</s> *(this has been fixed)*, and B) It isn't applicable to arrow functions.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711243/typesafe-event-handlers-with-preact-typescript) is similar, but it's not about typing the event object per se and the code in that question is no longer problematic because they're using an inline handler and Preact has moved on since then. ([The issue](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/1930) that [Marvin Hagemeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755391/marvinhagemeister) references in his answer remains open. Perhaps this question relates to that issue.)

To be clear, using `JSX.TargetedEvent` isn't a problem and I'm not complaining about it.  It's still just a single import, etc. (Perhaps usage is a bit more verbose, but that's easily solved with a type alias.) My concern is just it feels kind of...bare metal...and I worry that I'm missing something.

---

¹ Here's that quote from the documentation:

> **Typing events**
>
> Preact emits regular DOM events. As long as your TypeScript project includes the `dom` library (set it in `tsconfig.json`), you have access to all event types that are available in your current configuration.
>
> ```typescript
> export class Button extends Component {
>   handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
>     event.preventDefault();
>     if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
>       alert(event.target.tagName); // Alerts BUTTON
>     }
>   }
>
>   render() {
>     return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.children}</button>;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> You can restrict event handlers by adding a type annotation for this to the function signature as the first argument. This argument will be erased after transpilation.
>
> ```typescript
> export class Button extends Component {
>   // Adding the this argument restricts binding
>   handleClick(this: HTMLButtonElement, event: MouseEvent) {
>     event.preventDefault();
>     if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
>       console.log(event.target.localName); // "button"
>     }
>   }
>
>   render() {
>     return (
>       <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.children}</button>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

---

² Using the `Button` class code above, TypeScript shows this error on the `button`'s `onClick` prop:

> ```
> Type '(this: HTMLButtonElement, event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<TargetedMouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>>'.
>   The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
>     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement'.(2322)
> jsx.d.ts(1235, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I use in my `Input` component in preact:

```
    private handleInput = (e: Event): void => {
        const { onChange } = this.mergedProps;

        const element = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        onChange?.(e as InputEvent, { ...this.mergedProps, value: element.value });
    };
```

When forwarding the event to the handler passed in via properties I cast it to `InputEvent` but `Event` already contains the `currentTarget` member.

Comment: Thanks, but just using the basic `Event` type is a step backward IMHO (and I did say -- a bit buried in the paragraph starting "The documentation..." -- that I don't want to use a type assertion to access `value`).